# CloudFormation !Select within !Equals

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have conditions like

```
Conditions:
  IsSqs: !Equals
    - !Select [2, !Split [':', !Ref EventSourceArn]]
    - "sqs"
  IsDynamo: !Equals
    - !Select [2, !Split [':', !Ref EventSourceArn]]
    - "dynamodb"
```

which are used to create resources like

```
  EventSourceMappingForSqs:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Condition: IsSqs
    Properties:
      EventSourceArn: !Ref EventSourceArn
      # snip

  EventSourceMappingForDynamo:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Condition: IsDynamo
    Properties:
      EventSourceArn: !Ref EventSourceArn
      # snip
```

I am able to successfully run the surrounding template, and I can see that the correct `EventSourceMapping` is created based on the value of `EventSourceArn`. i.e. I get `EventSourceMappingForSqs` when I pass in an SQS queue ARN.

But, the [CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#w2ab1c21c24c21c45) say that my usage of `!Select` within `!Equals` is not supported:

> You can use the following functions in all other condition functions,
>   such as `Fn::Equals` and `Fn::Or`:
>
> - `Fn::FindInMap`
> - `Ref`
> - Other condition functions

Can or should I trust my successful template, and ignore the docs? Or might I be relying on a bug or accidental behaviour?

Is there an alternate, docs-compliant way of doing what I am trying to do?

Comment: I think you are safe. I see no logical reason as to why they should not be legal. Alternative probably would be to use `custom resource` to create the resource, but i will not call that a good alternative.